# Nonparametric test of a weighted mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

I have n multivariate observations (in this case 2-dimensional) that are drawn i.i.d., and I compute a weighted mean - in this particular case, a convolution with a Gaussian kernel.

I would like to be able to reject the null hypothesis that this weighted mean is zero.

Since this is a weighted mean, I don't seem to be able to do the Hotelling T2 test, but with unknown variances*, I can't seem to find anything else.

Is there a non-parametric test that I might use?

*In theory, I can estimate these. But for some of them, I have a sample size of 6 and these get difficult to trust in high dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try computing empirical bootstrap intervals & testing if the intervals contain your null value. The bootstrap does not generally rely on parametric assumptions beyond independent sampling.

Comment: To clarify, would the empirical intervals I consider be assumed to have a normal distribution?
This seems to make sense from Central Limit Theorem, but I'm not sure if the expected distribution of a population of weighted means is more exotic.

Comment: What do you mean? One typically doesn't think about intervals having a distribution. If you mean the distribution backing the interval (the empirical distribution), there are no distributional assumptions imposed. The purpose of using the bootstrap is that we aren't sure what this distribution looks like. So no, the empirical distribution can take any shape and inference on empirical intervals will still be valid.

Comment: Ah, I was asking about how the CI were derived, but I see it now. Thanks.